# Doctrine QueryBuilder leftJoin + MEMBER OF fails to work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

This piece of code failse to produce the correct results:

```
$queryBuilder
            ->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.building', $rootAlias), 'building')
            ->andWhere(':user MEMBER OF building.owners OR :user MEMBER OF building.managers')
            ->setParameter('user', $user);
```

whereas this returns a correct result:

```
$queryBuilder
            ->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.building', $rootAlias), 'building')
            ->andWhere('building.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', 1);
```

$user is properly defined and member of building.managers.

Answer (score 0):

It was a caching issue apparently. The above code works.